# IE7 Text Resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've used pixels to determine the size of my fonts on a website. All the text resizes fine in Chrome, Firefox etc, using the zoom feature. However in IE7 (and IE6/8, I guess) the fonts don't resize using the Text Size menu, they just stay the same.

Now I'm thinking the only solution to this is switching to `ems` - but is there any solution I could write in JS to target / fix only IE?

Comment: A javascript solution would be an expensive hack. Just normalize your font size on your body tag by using 62.5% which gives you a base 10pt font size you can increase/decrease easily. e.g., 1.2em roughly equals 12pt, 1.4em is 14pt, 0.8em is 8pt and so on.

Comment: Thanks Jared. I have a lot of text buttons styled with paddings and the like. Will I have to redo these paddings / margins etc in `ems`?

Comment: No just fonts are the problem in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you know otherwise, assume that hardly anyone has IE7 or 6 anyway. IE8 has a zoom feature, so that's OK. On approximately 50 small business sites I have data for, in the last month 0.5% of visitors were using IE6, 4% had IE7 and 12% had IE8.

We don't support IE6 or 7, but we do test and check things look basically right there.

Assuming that you do want to allow this minor feature (assumedly people who need accessibility the most will not be using these notoriously inaccessible browsers!) in IE6 and 7, you do need to use ems rather than px, and you'll really need to use it for everything, not just font-size, as otherwise the boxes won't scale properly either.

Comment: Sorry, should of been specific. The site is targeting students and could be used *in* schools. Where they will still be rocking IE7, I reckon. I'm going to redo the sizes using ems.

Comment: I worked in a school until last month, and we used IE9 as minimum, with Chrome installed as well. I'd be amazed if a school was using these old browsers. I'd still use ems anyway to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

in internet explorer 6 & 7 you cannot increase or decrease font-size that is set in pixel in your css.

For that to work you have to use EM's as font-size value.

[Read this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/)